# How to grab certain lines of a CSV file and save them in individual files

Tags: ruby

I have a CSV file with many lines:

```
Username,Year,Month,Match (0-60%),Match (60-65%),Match (65-70%),Match (70-75%),Match (75-80%),Match 
(80-85%),Match (85-90%),Match (90-95%),Match (95-100%),Match (100%),New_total,Edit_total,Review_total
Joe,2020,3,52,0,5,2,3,2,0,5,0,0,69,142,337
Engineering,2020,3,6469,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,6469,82,0
User_TR1_ES_ES,2020,3,112,3,0,0,0,14,10,0,0,2,141,3,0
User_TR1_FR_FR,2020,3,66,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,71,82,0
User_TR1_JA_JP,2020,3,35,49,56,114,0,21,22,66,62,0,425,630,0
User_TR1_KO_KR,2020,3,60,0,0,0,0,0,10,0,0,0,70,0,0
User_TR1_NL_NL,2020,3,61,2,41,59,15,31,11,13,2,0,235,0,0
User_TR1_PL_PL,2020,3,134,17,41,57,15,31,21,13,0,0,329,15,0
User_TR1_PT_BR,2020,3,37,0,2,0,0,12,0,0,0,22,73,53,0
Marie,2020,3,37,15,8,2,0,2,0,5,0,0,69,40,0
Charly,2020,3,224,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,224,28,0
Joseph,2020,3,56,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,56,0,0
```

I want to create individual CSV files for only the lines that include any of the `User_XXX_XX_XX` strings in the first column of the line. Other lines should be ignored. Finally, all the resulting files should be named after each of these first elements.

For instance:

```
User_TR1_ES_ES.csv
User_TR1_PT_BR.csv
```

My code so far is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'csv'
require 'fileutils'

this_dir = File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__))
original_dir = File.join(this_dir, '_Original')

#working with the .CSV file, there should be only one, and always be .CSV....
puts "Finding a .CSV file..."
full_path = Dir.glob('**/*.csv')
full_path.each do |csv|
  puts "CSV file found: #{File.basename(csv)}"
end

new_path = File.join(this_dir, full_path[0])

#I start reading the CSV file found in the folder
parsed_data = CSV.read(new_path)

#I grab the header in a separate variable
header = parsed_data.shift

#I created a constant to look for lines where the first elements meets the desired string, not sure about it...
USER_NAME = 'User' + '_' + 'TR' + 1..10 + ([a-z].upcase * 2) + '_' + ([a-z].upcase * 2)

#I want loop through each line and look for the those that includes the constant in the first element
CSV.foreach(new_path) do |row|
  row.first[0].include?(USER_NAME)

  #create inviduals files in a same location
  new_dir = File.join(this_dir, '_result')
  FileUtils.mkdir(new_dir)
  newfiles = File.join(new_dir, CONSTANT, '.csv')

  CSV.open(newfiles, 'w+') do |csv|
    csv << header
    csv << captured_row
  end
```

I'm having trouble  looping through the lines and grabbing the ones that I want.

Comment: Don't do `full_path = Dir.glob('**/*.csv')`. On a big disk with lots of files your program will stop while the directories are searched. Use Ruby's [Find](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.1/libdoc/find/rdoc/Find.html) class instead.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your code isn't syntactically correct; You're missing an `end` statement. See "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)". While Ruby doesn't require it, maintaining correct indentation will help you debug code.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I wouldn't even bother treating the file as CSV as that's not important when you can easily grab the `USER_...` lines:

```
header = nil

DATA.each_line { |l|
  if header.nil?
    header = l
    next
  end

  fn = l[/^User_TR1_[^,]+/]
  next unless fn

  File.write(fn + '.csv', header + l)
}

__END__
Username,Year,Month,Match (0-60%),Match (60-65%),Match (65-70%),Match (70-75%),Match (75-80%),Match (80-85%),Match (85-90%),Match (90-95%),Match (95-100%),Match (100%),New_total,Edit_total,Review_total
Joe,2020,3,52,0,5,2,3,2,0,5,0,0,69,142,337
Engineering,2020,3,6469,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,6469,82,0
User_TR1_ES_ES,2020,3,112,3,0,0,0,14,10,0,0,2,141,3,0
User_TR1_FR_FR,2020,3,66,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,71,82,0
User_TR1_JA_JP,2020,3,35,49,56,114,0,21,22,66,62,0,425,630,0
User_TR1_KO_KR,2020,3,60,0,0,0,0,0,10,0,0,0,70,0,0
User_TR1_NL_NL,2020,3,61,2,41,59,15,31,11,13,2,0,235,0,0
User_TR1_PL_PL,2020,3,134,17,41,57,15,31,21,13,0,0,329,15,0
User_TR1_PT_BR,2020,3,37,0,2,0,0,12,0,0,0,22,73,53,0
Marie,2020,3,37,15,8,2,0,2,0,5,0,0,69,40,0
Charly,2020,3,224,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,224,28,0
Joseph,2020,3,56,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,56,0,0
```

Which created:

```
-rw-r--r--@  1 TTM  staff   256B May  3 17:05 User_TR1_ES_ES.csv
-rw-r--r--@  1 TTM  staff   253B May  3 17:05 User_TR1_FR_FR.csv
-rw-r--r--@  1 TTM  staff   263B May  3 17:05 User_TR1_JA_JP.csv
-rw-r--r--@  1 TTM  staff   253B May  3 17:05 User_TR1_KO_KR.csv
-rw-r--r--@  1 TTM  staff   259B May  3 17:05 User_TR1_NL_NL.csv
-rw-r--r--@  1 TTM  staff   262B May  3 17:05 User_TR1_PL_PL.csv
-rw-r--r--@  1 TTM  staff   255B May  3 17:05 User_TR1_PT_BR.csv
```

and look like:

```
cat User_TR1_ES_ES.csv

Username,Year,Month,Match (0-60%),Match (60-65%),Match (65-70%),Match (70-75%),Match (75-80%),Match (80-85%),Match (85-90%),Match (90-95%),Match (95-100%),Match (100%),New_total,Edit_total,Review_total
User_TR1_ES_ES,2020,3,112,3,0,0,0,14,10,0,0,2,141,3,0
```

In the example, I'm taking advantage of Ruby's ability to store data after the `__END__` of the code. `DATA` is created by Ruby as a file handle to the content after `__END__`, so pay no attention to that man behind the curtain.

Just read the input file using `File.foreach`, grab the first line as the header, the loop back and read the next line. From that point, just look for lines that match the `/^User_TR1_[^,]+/` pattern.

Here's what is being returned:

```
'Engineering,2020,3,6469,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,6469,82,0'[/^User_TR1_[^,]+/] # => nil
'User_TR1_ES_ES,2020,3,112,3,0,0,0,14,10,0,0,2,141,3,0'[/^User_TR1_[^,]+/] # => "User_TR1_ES_ES"
```

So, if the line isn't a `User...` line `nil` is returned causing the code to loop. If the line *is* a `User...` line, the string will be returned, the code will fall through, and output the header and line using `File.write`.

Also, if it was my system, I'd convert the filenames to lower-case when creating them. As a systems-admin I learned to avoid upper-case or mixed-case in filenames because they're opportunities to misspell the filename.

```
'User_TR1_ES_ES'.downcase + '.csv' # => "user_tr1_es_es.csv"
```

Also, see my comment above about using Ruby's [Find](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.1/libdoc/find/rdoc/Find.html) class. It's easy to implement and is very efficient.

Comment: I'm not skipping the header, I'm grabbing it for later reuse.

Answer (score 1):

Let's first create a CSV file:

```
CSV_In = 't.csv'
```

```
File.write CSV_In, <<~_ 
Username,Year,Month,Match (0-60%)
Joe,2020,3,52
User_TR1_ES_ES,2020,3,112
User_TR1_FR_FR,2020,3,66
User_TR1_JA_JP,2020,3,35
Marie,2020,3,37
_
  #=> 140
```

If the CSV file is large we would want to use [CSV::foreach](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-foreach) to read the file row-by-row (i.e., line-by-line). When using `foreach` (with a block) to read a CSV file with headers, the block variable is a row of the file. Therefore, no `CSV` object is available to extract the headers, which we will need when writing files.

To use `foreach`, therefore, we must read the headers as a separate step, before invoking `foreach`. One way of doing that without reading the entire file into memory is the following:

```
require 'csv'

csv = CSV.open(CSV_In, headers:true)
headers = csv.gets.headers
  #=> ["Username", "Year", "Month", "Match (0-60%)"] 
csv.close
```

See [CSV::open](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-open) and [CSV#gets](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-i-shift) (aka `shift`) and [CSV::Row#headers](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV/Row.html#method-i-headers.

We can now open the CSV file with `foreach` and step through the rows, writing the output files where appropriate.

```
CSV.foreach(CSV_In, headers: true) do |row|
  user_name = row['Username']
  CSV.open("#{user_name}.csv", "w") {|csv| csv << headers << row} if
    user_name.match?(/\AUser_TR1(?:_[A-Z]{2}){2}\z/)
end
```

Let's confirm the files were written correctly.

```
puts File.read "User_TR1_ES_ES.csv"
  Username,Year,Month,Match (0-60%)
  User_TR1_ES_ES,2020,3,112 
puts File.read "User_TR1_FR_FR.csv"
  Username,Year,Month,Match (0-60%)
  User_TR1_FR_FR,2020,3,66 
puts File.read "User_TR1_JA_JP.csv"
  Username,Year,Month,Match (0-60%)
  User_TR1_JA_JP,2020,3,35
```

The regular expression could be modified as needed. One possibility, for example, is the following:

```
/\AUser_[A-Z]{2}\d(?:_[A-Z]{2}){2}\z/
```

One advantage of using `CSV` methods (as opposed to `IO` and `File` methods) to read the input file is that the code need not be changed if in future the order of the columns is changed.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this code, should work even with large csv files.

```
header = nil
CSV.open(path_to_your_csv_file, 'r', :headers => true).each do |line|
  header = line unless header
  if line[0].match? /User_TR\d_[a-zA-Z]{2}_[a-zA-z]{2}/
    file_name = "#{line[0].downcase}.csv"
    existed = File.exists? file_name
    CSV.open(file_name, 'a+') do |row|
      row << header unless existed
      row << line
    end
  end
end
```